# Delivery errors to Facebook proxy email addresses

Tags: email, facebook, proxy

We have used Facebook Connect on our Web site for some time now and never experienced problems reaching customers that use proxy email addresses. However, recently there were a few occasions of messages bouncing back from Facebook with the error message below. The problem seems to be known (e.g., at [forum.developers.facebook.net](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=29568)), but I have found no reasonable explanations of this error and how to prevent it. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
<app+*******************@xmail.facebook.com>
   (expanded from
   <app+*******************@proxymail.facebook.com>):
   Command died with status 255: " /usr/local/bin/php
   /var/www/scripts/xmail/process_email_api.php >> /var/log/proxy.log
   2>>/var/log/proxy.log"
Reporting-MTA: dns; gpmgw002.snc1.facebook.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 6E93E23FC006
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; *****
Arrival-Date: Thu,  2 Feb 2012 02:51:40 -0800 (PST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; app+*******************@xmail.facebook.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;app+*******************@proxymail.facebook.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.3.0
Diagnostic-Code: x-unix; unknown mail system error 255
```

Comment: Email delivery isn't guaranteed the first time. What happens if you try again later? And, why isn't your MTA retrying later for you anyway (or are you bypassing a local MTA completely)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a PHP script that Facebook tried to run had an error of some sort. If it persists, maybe you want to contact them.

Comment: I contacted them, and the problem seems to be resolved now: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/101582946637943

Comment: FWIW, the link brought me to a page which looks like they just closed the bug report for lack of feedback. You have to click open the older messages to see that they in fact deployed a fix back in February (and requested feedback on whether the fix actually worked; but apparently, it did).